# Visual Studio 2010 with AnkhSVN - project cloning

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, project, clone, ankhsvn

I have a project in VS2010 and that project exists in SVN through AnkhSVN.

I want to create a project with the same code as the existing project.  I don't want to branch.  Has to be a completely different project, but I want to start with the existing files from an existing project.  I do not want the name from the current project listed anywhere in the existing project.

How do I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific operation in SVN as **branching**, all operations (tagging, branching) are just essentially making copies within SVN repository (however on SVN server these are not separate copies, i.e. you are not doubling space on server side, but instead the cost is almost nothing). So, all you need is just copy it to another location and start working there:

```
$ svn copy svn://host.example.com/repos/project/trunk \
           svn://host.example.com/repos/new_project/trunk \
      -m "Creating a new_project based on project"
```

After that, you probably would want to **switch** local working copy to point to the new_project location on the repository:

```
$ svn svn switch svn://host.example.com/repos/new_project/trunk .
```

Comment: Thanks - couldn't see the forest for the trees.  I appreciate your help